# Domain seedwork vs. Cross-cutting - sorting stuff

Tags: domain-driven-design

Domain [seedwork](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Seedwork.html) is a separated project with common domain logic: bases for entity, VO, Repository and UoW contracts, Specifications etc.

But I can't decide where to place following:

1. Validators.
   I want to keep Validation Rules separated from Entities. Validation Rule base must be in Domain seedwork as well as Validator contract, but what about Validator implementation?
2. Business Rules Evaluators.
   Same situation but with Business Rules and Business Rules Evaluators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid trying to do validation in one place.  The notion of *one size fits all* is generally nonsense, particularly in DDD.  You can add the most basic validation into your entities, to ensure your entities are never in an invalid state.  Apart from that, your validation logic should probably go where you are validating, i.e. UI validation logic, should go in the UI/presentation layer.

Business rules should go in your domain model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to write that I am talking about services server part of system. Of cause, UI validation logic would be in presentation layer. But it's about user input, not entities.

I don't know whether to create validators for DTOs, but I think this is unnecessary (ad hoc checks for null will be enough) and validation things for Domain operations is part of Domain.

Comment: If you use *value objects* for various values, like `FirstName`, `PostalCode` or `Email`, etc. then entities that take these value objects will automatically be performing some sort of domain level validation every time the entity is created/updated.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about wrapping all (even `Firstname`) values in _value objects_. Isn't it overcomplication?

Comment: There's trade-offs with what to define as a *value object*, `FirstName` is probably a more debatable one, but some like `PostalCode` would bake stronger validation into your *entities*.  To be honest I've only defined a handful in my personal projects, but there seems plenty of people on here who swear that you can't have too many custom *value objects*.

Comment: I am the one of those who believes that _entities_ should not always be valid, and validation should be carried out for actions (ie _entity is valid for ..._, not _entity is valid_). Therefore, _validation rules_ and _validators_ (with lists of rules) is explicit concepts (not hiden in _entities_ and _value objects_). But thank you for expanding my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

While I was formulating the question, answer came. Please, correct me if I missed something.

Domain seedwork must contain common logic used only by Domain. Logic that can be used in multiple layers, must be in Cross-cutting.

Therefore, Validator contract and implementation must be in Cross-cutting as well as Business Rules Evaluator. Validation Rule base and Business Rule base is used only by Domain and must be in Domain seedwork.

**UPDATE.**
There is another option: Validator and Business Rules Evaluator is bases living in Domain seedwork and used for specific implementations like CustomerCanPersistedValidator.